# What XPath expression should I use to fetch the number of likes and comments on a YouTube video?

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, youtube, google-sheets-formula

I'm using the "IMPORTXML" function on Google Spreadsheets to get the number of likes and comments on any given YouTube video. However, I can't find the right XPath, and all I've tried return an empty value.

I used ChroPath to extract the XPath of the comments and likes count, but to no success.

This is the XPath that I've been using for amount of comments:

```
//yt-formatted-string[@class='count-text style-scope ytd-comments-header-renderer']
```

And this is for amount of likes:

```
//div[@id='info']//ytd-toggle-button-renderer[1]//a[1]//yt-icon-button[1]
```

When I try those it just says the content is empty. What is the correct XPath that I should be using to get the number of likes and comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the number of likes of the video on YouTube.
- You want to put the value to the Spreadsheet.

How about this formula? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Sample formula:

```
=VALUE(IMPORTXML(A1,"//button[@title='I like this']/span"))
```

- In this case, the cell "A1" is the URL like `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=###`.
- Xpath is `//button[@title='I like this']/span"`.

#### Sample script of Google Apps Script:

As another method for retrieving the number of likes, if you use Advanced Google services of Google Apps Script, the sample script is as follows.

```
var count = YouTube.Videos.list("statistics", {id: "###"}).items[0].statistics.likeCount;
```

- `###` is the video's ID.

#### References:

- [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342)
- [VALUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094220)
- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: That's it! Could you help me find the XPath that will yield the amount of comments? Thanks.

Comment: @nmaurok Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize that my answer was incomplete. About your next question, unfortunately, it seems that the number of comments cannot be retrieved by the xpath. In this case, I recommend to use a script like `var count = YouTube.Videos.list("statistics", {id: "###"}).items[0].statistics.commentCount;`. I deeply apologize that I couldn't answer for your all questions.

Comment: I started using Google Script as you suggested and it worked like a charm. Thanks so much!

Comment: @nmaurok Thank you for replying. Thank you for testing the Google Apps Script. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

for YT likes you could use:

```
=IF(ISNA(IMPORTXML("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MkgR0SxmMKo","(//*[contains(@class,'like-button-renderer-like-button')])[1]"))=TRUE,0,
         IMPORTXML("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MkgR0SxmMKo","(//*[contains(@class,'like-button-renderer-like-button')])[1]"))
```